# Find $x'_s(1,\sqrt{2})$ with $x(s,t) = e^{2s^2−t^2}$ using the limit

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I did:

$$x'_s = \lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \frac{x(s,\sqrt{2})-x(1,\sqrt{2})}{s} = \lim_{s\rightarrow 1} \frac{1-1}{s} = 0$$

This is wrong because the derivative at that point should be 4. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivative of $x$ with respect to $s$ is

\begin{align}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}&=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x(s+h,t)-x(s,t)}{h} \\&=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{2(s+h)^2-t^2}-e^{2s^2-t^2}}{h}\\&\overset{L.H.}=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{4(h+s)e^{2 h^2 + 4 h s + 2 s^2 - t^2} }{1}\\&=
4se^{2s^2-t^2}
\end{align}

where

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\Big|_{(1,\sqrt{2})}=4$$